# How to access variables from another component in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a component here with some variables inside this.state:

```
class Landing extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      searchQuery: "",
      searchQueryWords: [],
    };
 }
//The rest of the component's rendering left out
```

searchQuery and searchQueryWords both get populated within this Landing component.

I have another component that is not a child to this one and I'd want to use those two populated variables for something else. This landing page comes before the other page on the website so there is no way to reach my other component without those variables having been established. Is there a way to do so, to send variables from one component to another like this?

If there does need to be a parent/child relationship to share these variables, how do I do so?

Comment: You're probably looking for React Contexts or Redux-like state management. You **could** lift the relevant state up, but it doesn't sound like that'd make sense here--but it's hard to say without more context.

Comment: FYI - [react redux count ](https://codesandbox.io/s/prod-silence-tqx2wc?file=/src/index.js) here is the example of react & redux counter app. check it out. you will need to choose state management lib.

Comment: Dave, when you say I could lift the relevant state up, what do you mean by that? To maybe provide more context, this landing component handles a search bar where the user enters a search phrase that gets stored into this searchQuery string. When the user searches, the results are a list of text files. A user will click a text file and the component that displays that page is the other one I'm referencing. It is here that I want to use these variables as a way to search these text files for the searchQuery string/words

Comment: [Here's some more information](https://react.dev/learn/sharing-state-between-components) on sharing state between components.

Answer (score 0):

To pass in some shared data between components that do not share a parent/child relation would be by using React's Context API.

Here is a link to one of the latest articles from Official React documentation, which provides a deeper insight to passing data deeply with React Context.

[Documentation](https://react.dev/learn/passing-data-deeply-with-context#the-problem-with-passing-props)

Answer (score -1):

You can use ContextAPI for solve this problem

As it seems that you are using class based components I will be sharing two links

This will cover ContextAPI for class based components
https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/context.html

If you have the possibility of using hooks to consume the context give it a try (Hooks can't be used in class based components)
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/react-usecontext

The main idea of Context API is that you create a Provider (that will have your state)

```
this.state = {
  searchQuery: "",
  searchQueryWords: [],
};
```

And you will have a consumer in this case the components that needs that state

The structure is more or less like this

- Provider (it is a component that receives the state, and methods that
  modify the state if you want) it needs to be the parent of the
  children in component tree) children doesn't have to be direct
  children (here is the magic)
- Child component will consume that
  through an API (useContext if using hooks or Context.Consumer
  component) check the links that I shared with you

So no matter where are the children you will have access to that info

Hope this answer helps you to find the right solution to your problem

Comment: Thanks! I'll check this out. I'm in an existing codebase that uses class components so I appreciate you giving information for that too. I'll try this and mention if things work

Answer (score -1):

I agree with the commenter Dave Newton that you could lift the state up, but disagree with him that it doesn't sound like you should. If you're using Context at any level (including State Management like Redux), that's really what's going on--there's just a level of obfuscation going on so that any interim levels of component between the higher level that knows about the persisted data and the lower level where it's used aren't aware of the data or responsible for passing it. However, this also creates a situation where it's not clear how that data is getting to its destination and creates coupling to the exact mechanism for retrieving that data, so I'm not a fan.

If you're going to raise state up, your component that is capturing the data now becomes just a dumb view that uses a callback to send the data it's capturing further up the component tree to a common ancestor of the two components. Then it will receive that data back as props and just display it (so it will act as a managed component). Now the ancestor component will have the value and can pass it into the other component that needs it as props.

Next, you can manually wire it up on Context. The problem with this is each Context can only hold a single value, so if you make a general policy of this, you will wind up with a rat's nest of Providers. Usually, that single value will contain two properties, one that is the value and the other that is a setter for the value. So you again have a callback and a value, only instead of getting these through props you have to glom onto a specific Context. For anyone familiar with the Service Locator pattern and why it came to be hated, this will feel icky, and rightfully so.

You can also use a dedicated state management library such as Redux. This might be the best solution if you expect to have lots of different state that you need to keep track of as the app grows. This again works basically the same way--you'll get a callback that notionally will let you set the state from your component and there will be a related way to retrieve the specific piece of state you care about. The difference is you're not directly changing the state in that callback, so in the layer where you do the actual change (in Redux it's called a reducer), you have flexibility to combine the requested change with other things you know about the state or to make additional changes based on the incoming value (e.g. change other parts of the state).

Additionally, you could choose to store the values entered on the landing page in the URL, either as route parameters or as part of a query string.

Comment: This is helpful, I'll take a look more into the context section as others have been suggesting similar things there. Thanks!

Comment: Sure, it always makes sense to pick the one that will make your code harder to maintain because it's popular. Glad I could help!